# HTML adjust spacing

Tags: html

If you go to http://tinyurl.com/6xdd8zl there is a page with a simple gif. I want the centre of the gif to be aligned to centre seam of the page. So far I'm just using

```
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <img src="http://jackdent.co.uk/hypw/bar.gif">
```

as a placeholder. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide will help you to achieve your goal in the correct way (**using CSS**): http://www.netmechainic.com/news/vol7/html_no10.htm

Answer (score 0):

HTML cannot do that on its own.  You need to create a stylesheet.  I recommend using CSS:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: They are not affiliated with w3c, but for the purpose of getting a beginner's walkthrough, they do a good job.  They taught me most of what I know about webdev.

Comment: This is also true for me, but it's always better to learn clean, proper, up to date coding practices from the start. I'm still to this day finding myself correcting bad habits I've learned from w3schools :]

Answer (score 0):

Get Chrome or Firefox, use the developer tools (I personally prefer Chrome) and play around with the css of that element - you'd want a margin-top rule similar to this:

```
img {
    margin-top:250px;
}
```